# inconsistent links coming out of make4ht

Tags: links, make4ht

I am working on a handbook and I am using latex to write it. I am able to produce PDFs and I also produce HTML content using make4ht (on an uptodate debian testing box).

handbook is here: https://github.com/eantoranz/conflict_book/tree/main/latex

I generate the HTML content like this:

```
make4ht conflicts.tex "xhtml,3"
```

The output looks more or less like what I am looking forward to:

http://www.ezconflict.com/en/conflicts.html

However, I noticed that the links that are at the top/bottom of pages are not consistent. Say, you go to **conventions**.

http://www.ezconflict.com/en/conflictsse5.html#x7-50000.5

There is a link at the top that says **next**. If I click on it, I would expect to be taken to the next part, which is the *Basics* Chapter, *What is a conflict?* section http://www.ezconflict.com/en/conflictsse6.html#x11-70001.1... or at least the *Basics* chapter http://www.ezconflict.com/en/conflictsch1.html#x10-60001.... instead we get taken to the third section in *Basics* Chapter, Terms and Acronyms http://www.ezconflict.com/en/conflictsse8.html

Is there something I am doing wrong when generating the HTML with make4t?

Comment: I created a ticket in make4ht. Will provide updates when I get them. https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/issues/36

Comment: links may need multiple compilations to work correctly. I've downloaded your TeX files and they work as expected when I compiled it on my machine, so from section `0.5` you go to TOC of chapter 1.

Comment: Ok.... that would be fine. For PDF generation I run pdflatex twice. How many times do I need to run make4ht?

Comment: I think two compilations should be fine. If you don't remove temporary files after compilation, the links should be stable after that. If you still get the error, it is possible that something is wrong with the Debian files, but I think it is unlikely.

Comment: If you don't mind providing that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: so is your issue fixed? :)

Comment: I think it is. Take a look for yourself: http://www.ezconflict.com/en/conflicts.html Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some features, most notably links and tables, TeX4ht needs multiple compilation steps. For this reason, `make4ht` runs LaTeX three times by default. In some cases, it needs even more LaTeX invocations. For this reason, you should not delete some temporary files created by TeX4ht, in particular, files with `.xref` or `.4tc` extensions.

You need fewer compilations once the temporary files are stable. When you just make changes in document text, you can even use the `draft` mode that `make4ht` provides (use `make4ht -m draft filename.tex`). It runs only one invocation of LaTeX, so it is much faster.